# How to add multiple images inside scroll view(Paging image slider) and full screen mode for pinch and zoom?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, autolayout, uicollectionview

I found many tutorials that explain over scroll view which we used to display multiple images inside scroll view.But,when i tried to zoom,which make me stuck.So,I search the other one and i found scroll view which was implemented with `UICollectionView`-->`MVCarouselCollectionView`.Its also complicated and have many steps to do to have perfect image sliding library also included full screen zoom feature.But,it have many errors also autolayout issue which i cant use it directly for rotating devices.

So,its there any other alternative 3rd party library like `MVCarouselCollectionView` which i can use easy in `Swift` with no autolayout issue?

Any help?
I found these library at githud also many tutorial on raywanderish and appcoda,but they don't explain it completely.Some are work on sliding images inside scrollview but for zooming,its not.When i tried to apply "hamasyou" with zoom view,stuck with its library which mean not worked out.

These are the libraries i found on web

https://github.com/bizz84/MVCarouselCollectionView

http://www.the-nerd.be/2015/06/22/tnimagesliderviewcontroller-image-slider-for-swift/

https://github.com/hamasyou/autolayout

Is there any way that i can do thing like "MVCarouselCollectionView" with no autolayout issue?Please,I really need help.I am stucking at this for a week.

I really need a good source to create image sliding with multiple images and zoom full screen feature.Thanks.

Comment: what do you return for viewForZoomingInScrollView delegate method?

Comment: I am still stuck m8 when i tried "https://github.com/hamasyou/autolayout" .I am still finding solution which one to return